# How do you reliably stop activity recognition after it was started?

Tags: android, google-play-services, activity-recognition

I have an alarm that starts activity recognition using a pending intent and an intent service. Starting works without problem, but I cannot stop the client to listen to updates. I ran ActivityRecognitionApi.removeActivityUpdates, I disconnected the activity recognition client and set it to null, set the intent to null, did stopSelf() on the intent service, nothing worked. This is for Android 4.* and 5, running the latest SDK, compat libraries and Google Play Services (api.GoogleApiClient).